# Processing parameters with * passed to unix

Tags: escape-characters, parameter

I am receiving a query via a configuration file in unix, for ex. Config file content will be in the format:

```
Table_name|query

ABC|select ABC.A,ABC.B from PQR left join (select * from ABC) on ABC.pk=PQR.pk
```

I am trying to process query part as below :

```
    while read line in config_file
    do
        query=`echo $line|awk -F "|" '{print $1}'`
        result=hive -e "$query"
        ...
```

However the '*' in query variable is getting expanded to the listing of files in the current directory

Could you please help how to escape the `*` character, i searched for the solution but could not find one.

Comment: have you tried the methods in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456496/8953000 ?

Comment: Quote the `$line` variable: `echo "$line"`. For further information see for example [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/65304)

Comment: It might generally be usefull to know on which OS exactly you are and which shell you are using.

Comment: See also [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123) and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803). Note here you could do `query=${line%%'|'*}`

Comment: Thanks for reply " resloved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Saket Mankar and welcome to the community!

You would need to enclose the `$line` variable with double quotes: `"$line"`.

That should solve your situation.